# Comparing values between records in a table using Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: database, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Consider a table with the following records in a Database:

```
>>> Table A:
Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
GGG     123    -
GGG     123    X
GGG     123    Y
KKK     786    X
MMM     999    Y
DDD     456    X
DDD     456    U
```

Wherever we have records with matching values in col_1 and col_2, and we have values X and Y in col_3, the records with X and Y must be deleted. In other cases, we should keep the records.
For example in the above table, the output should look like this:

```
>>> Output_Table:
    Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
    GGG     123    -
    KKK     786    X
    MMM     999    Y
    DDD     456    X
    DDD     456    U
```

How this scenario can be implemented (using expression transformation, variable ports, lookup and so on...)? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple scenarios. And i am not sure if your issue is exactly like you described but i will answer as per your question.

Assuming Col_3 can have 'X','Y' - as hardcoded value you want to remove. The values you are trying to remvoe are hardcoded.

1. First sort the data based on Col_1,Col_2.
2. Then use EXP transformation and create 7 ports like below. Here we will compare one row with its previous row and see if they are same or not. If same, then concat col3 into one single column.

```
col1
col2
in_col3
v_col3= iif(v_prev_col1=col1 and v_prev_col2=col2,col3,v_col3||''||col3)
v_prev_col1=col1
v_prev_col2=col2
o_col3=v_col3
```

3. After that use an aggregator - group by ports will be col1,col2. And then col3 will be MAX(o_col3) from expression before. Agg will stamp concatenated col3 into one single column.
4. Then add a filter like below to check if you have XY or YX for duplicate rows.

```
iif(max_col3='XY' or reverse(max_col3)='XY',FALSE,TRUE)  -- You can place any hardcode values here.
```

EDIT :
5. Now, if you want to get original data (like in comments) excluding `XY` combination, then use a joiner.
use a joiner now, join output from step 4 and output of step 1. It will be a normal join on Col_1,Col_2.
And the output of the joiner will have no `XY` combination.

Whole mapping should look like this

```
           |->2.EXP-->3.AGG-->4.FIL--|  
-->1.SRT ->|------------------------>|->5.JNR--...--> TGT
```

Comment: Hello Koushik, I found a small bug in your proposed solution. In this case, for two rows with the same values in col1 and col2 and other values than X and Y in in_col3 (for example values U and X), v_col3 will also have a concatenated value and we have in this case UX in v_col3, and after applying the filter and removing the lines with XY combination from o_col3, it still has the value UX, although the result must be U and X in 2 separate lines.

Comment: i understand. so you join  above output with main table to get actual data. i edited my solution.